# How to implement full specialization templates member function within partial specialization templates class

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template class Foo with two template args and one template member function.

I want to make member function specialization while the template class is partial specialization, but the following code compiled failed by g++

```
    template <typename A, typename B>
    class Foo 
    {
    public:
        template<typename C> void bar();
    };
    
    template<> template<typename T> inline void Foo<T, int>::bar<float>() {
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        Foo<double, int> foo;
        foo.bar<float>();
    
        return 0;
    
    }
```

g++ says:

**error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token**

**template<> template inline void Foo<T, int>::bar() {**

I've tried

```
template<typename T> template<> inline void Foo<T, int>::bar<float>() {
```

and g++ complains more

Can it be possible and how to make it ?

Comment: worth a read: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm. Most of the time it is possible to specialize a type rather than a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[temp.expl.spec]/17](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#17):

> **In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.** In such an explicit specialization declaration, the keyword template followed by a template-parameter-list shall be provided instead of the template<> preceding the explicit specialization declaration of the member. The types of the template-parameters in the template-parameter-list shall be the same as those specified in the primary template definition.

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that **the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.**

for your code:

```cpp
template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo{
public:
    template<typename C> void bar();
};
    
template<typename T> // for `Foo`
template<>           // for `bar`
inline void Foo<T, int>::bar<float>(){}
    
int main(){
    Foo<double, int> foo;
    foo.bar<float>();
    return 0;
}
```

it's ill-formed because `bar` is **explicitly specialized** but `Foo` is **NOT**.

Comment: Do you means, if I want to specialize a class member template, I should make the outer class fully specialized. specialize a class member template inside an template class or partial specialized template class is no allowed?

Comment: @libgcc yes. so you can think about what you really want to do. if that's exactly what you want, try [Klaus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67585378/14098766). but usually it's not the best way in cpp style when standard forbid us to do that thing.

Answer (score 1):

As you specialize your class template, you have get a full independent class for the specialization. And as this, you have to write your class spezialisation with the function `foo` in it.

Example:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class Foo 
{
    public:
        template<typename C> void bar() { std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl;}
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,int>
{
    public:
        template<typename C> void bar(){ std::cout << "spezialized" << std::endl; }

};

int main()
{
    Foo<double, int> foo;
    foo.bar<float>();

    Foo<double, char> foo2;
    foo2.bar<int>();

    return 0;

}
```

I believe you try to do something different :-)

If you want to have a specialization of a member only in a specific specialization and in non specialized cases you want to see the generic functionality of your class template, you can do it like:

Example:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    template<typename C> void bar() { std::cout << "Generic" << std::endl;}
    void other() { std::cout << "Other" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
class Foo: public Base
{
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,int>: public Base
{
    public:
        template<typename C> void bar(){ std::cout << "spezialized" << std::endl; }

};

int main()
{
    Foo<double, int> foo;
    foo.bar<float>();
    foo.other();

    Foo<double, char> foo2;
    foo2.bar<int>();
    foo2.other();

    return 0;
}
```